# how to know the branch name from the graph line in git?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using source tree by Atlassian to debug the regression issues via git repository. My question is how can I make out the branch name from the graph lines in git? I see various colors like brown, blue, and red. My question is what is the branch name for these corresponding color lines -

Here is the graph --

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that git tortoise windows is the answer to it. It  provides a very friendly graph.

Comment: I installed TortoiseGIT now due to this answer only to find out that the graph is equal to Sourcetree with no branch column and not like TortoiseHG. Why is this the graph more "friendly" to you?

Answer (score 6):

The name floats upwards, to the most recent commit for that branch.  If the commit was a merge, Sourcetree automatically adds the branch name to the commit message. Otherwise, you will just have to scroll up until the label of the same color is visible (unless Atlassian adds this in the future). You might be able to create a [custom action](https://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/02/08/custom-actions-more-power-to-you/) for a commit within Sourcetree and call `git log` with the commit hash.

Reference: http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-3.html

Comment: Also, the colors [don't mean anything](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/179335/sourcetree-what-do-colors-of-branches-and-tags-mean)!